# how to get two rows from sql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in sql database named releases this table has 2 rows with the same id like (260) now I would like to get this two rows into my php file I used this function (mysqli_fetch_assoc) but the output gives one single row only (in array) and didn't give me the other one. So how can I get the two rows with array and how to call specific record from this array ???

Here is my code:

```
$conn = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM ps4_media_releases_ref LEFT JOIN ps4_releases ON ps4_media_releases_ref.rid=ps4_releases.release_id
                            WHERE mid = {$media_id2}");

$result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($conn);
$result2=mysqli_num_rows($conn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution is (irrespective of technology, modify according to technology)

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE ROWNUM <= number;
```

example

```
SELECT *
FROM Persons
WHERE ROWNUM <=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is nothing wrong with php code you have written.

The problem is with query.

Just run your query in my sql client and double confirm that it returns two rows.

*Note:*

In Doubt double check the count of the associative array returned

```
echo count($result)
```

-- Update

`mysql_fetch_assoc` 
*will return one row at a time till it returns all the row*

so try below code snippet

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["RecordName or ColumnName"];
    ///Get as many records as you want
}
```

Comment: ok you are right it give me 13 element that is mean it generate one row only but i need to call the other row it have the same id so the query should give m all rows have the same id right????? so why it give me one row only????

Comment: @H.Ali - Sorry I was away ! how much the count of $result echoes

Comment: 13 element (10 element from first table and 3 from second table)

Comment: Ok..Now you have 13 rows ..so problem solved huh ! you were expecting 2 rows..so you have change the query in a way that gives two rows..

Comment: i mean 13 record not 13 rows (if it work well it should gives me 26 record not 13)

Comment: @H.Ali - Now I understood your problem...I have updated my answer..check and let me know

Comment: @H.Ali - do you have any doubts ?